# Where is ${filename} coming from?

Tags: javascript, jquery, amazon-s3, uploadify

At http://www.uploadify.com/forums/discussion/1416/uploading-to-amazon-s3/p1

Terebentina's comment. In the 'key:' section. where does ${filename} come from?

Alternatively, instead of making it look like:

```
"key": encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent("40/20091216-120535/${filename}"))
```

I'd like to make it look something like:

```
"key": encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent("40/20091216-120535/foobar${file_extension}"))
```

Sadly, `${file_extension}` does not exist. Anyone know how this can be done?

**EDIT:**

Upon further digging. I found this http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1434 which now brings me to the conclusion that `${filename}` is a variable used by S3 and not uploadify.

The questions still stands. What if we was to have specific names for all uploaded files and keep the extensions dynamic. For example: foobar.mp4, foobar.txt, foobar.flv, etc. How should we go about this?

Comment: looks like some sort of templating ...

Comment: Can't find any information about such templating in Uploadify. Maybe that was just like a label specially for forum answer where Terebentina just wanted to show place where you should put filename? If you want to put some dynamic values for scriptData, simply use .uploadifySettings('scriptData', {...}) in your upload event handler.

Comment: @RReverser nah. I've tested this with and without it when uploading a file. I can confirm `${filename}` is not just a label just for the filename. Its an actual templating variable Uploadify uses. It's the same case in http://www.kiakroas.com/blog/44/ . Can't find anything in the Uploadify docs. But I'm hoping there's a templating variable for file extensions as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1434 `${filename}` is a special variable Amazon S3 uses when a file is uploaded to them.